# Define routes with controllers as service in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, routes, controller

As per documentation:

> In addition to using the logical name or the fully-qualified class
>   name, Symfony supports a third way of referring to a controller. This
>   method uses just one colon separator (e.g. service_name:indexAction)
>   and refers to the controller as a service (see How to define
>   Controllers as Services).

With this controller as a service (id is `gremo_skebby.controller.report`):

```xml
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
                        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="gremo_skebby.controller.report.class">
            Gremo\SkebbyBundle\Controller\ReportController
        </parameter>
        <parameter key="gremo_skebby.request.param_converter.report_event.class">
            Gremo\SkebbyBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ReportEventParamConverter
        </parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="gremo_skebby.request.param_converter.report_event"
            class="%gremo_skebby.request.param_converter.report_event.class%">
            <tag name="request.param_coverter" />
        </service>
        <service id="gremo_skebby.controller.report" 
            class="%gremo_skebby.controller.report.class%">
            <argument id="dispatcher" type="service" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

How can I define the route `/skebby/notify` in `routing.xml` file?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
                        http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="gremo_skebby_report_notify" pattern="/skebby/notify">
        <default key="_controller">???</default>
        <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the action method is called `notifyAction`, then `gremo_skebby.controller.report:notifyAction`.